# How to move certain files from one directory to another, while maintaining directory structure

Tags: linux, bash

How do you move files from a source directory to a destination directory, with the destination directory maintaining the original directory structure of the source directory?

For example, given source directory

```
source
├── source_sub
│   ├── ex_one.txt
│   ├── ex_two.sh
│   ├── source_sub_sub
|   │   ├── ex_three.txt
|   │   ├── ex_four.sh
│   ├── source_unmoved_dir
|   │   ├── ex_five.sh
```

I would want to move all the text files from the source directory to the destination directory so that the result is this:

```
destination
├── source_sub
│   ├── ex_one.txt
│   ├── source_sub_sub
|   │   ├── ex_three.txt
```

In the destination, the directory from source called `source_unmoved_dir` is not moved because it does not contain any `.txt` files.

So far, I am looping through all the files and directories in source. When I encounter a file, I move it simply using `mv $file $dest`. For directories, I have only come up with this `mv $file $dest/`. This will recursively move directories and subdirectories from source to destination. However, it also moves every single file in the directory and its subdirectories. I don't know how to only add `.txt` files in the directories/subdirectories.

Here is my script so far:

```
for file in "$src"/*; do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then
        mv $file $dest
    elif [[ -f $file ]]; then
        if [[ $file == *.txt ]]; then
            mv $file $dest
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: If this is a "one off", I'd just 1) dump the files/directories I wanted to move into a text file, 2) Find an editor with "block mode", 3) set the leftmost column to `mv `, 4) Block edit the right column to whatever directory path you wanted that file on that line moved to, 5) Execute the script when you're satisfied.  Even if you had several hundred files, it's probably faster/easier than thinking of a "clever" way to do it.  And a *LOT* "safer" (one bug in the "clever" script could easily trash your filesystem).

Comment: That's ingenious actually. I will try to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `find` where we loop over all .txt files found in the source directory. This command says "find all files in the path `${SOURCE_DIR}` that are files (`-type f`) that end in .txt (`-name "*.txt"`)".

For each file found in this way, we:

- figure out the desired `new_path` to the file in the destination directory (not including the name of the file itself)
- make that `new_path` (`mkdir -p` doesn't care if the directory already exists, so it's ok if we try to create the same (sub)directory multiple times)
- move the file to its `new_path`

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR=source
DEST_DIR=destination

for txt_file in $(find "${SOURCE_DIR}" -type f -name "*.txt"); do
        new_path=$(dirname "$txt_file" | sed "s~${SOURCE_DIR}~${DEST_DIR}~")
        mkdir -p "${new_path}"
        mv "${txt_file}" "${new_path}"
done
```

You'll just want to replace the definitions of `SOURCE_DIR` and `DEST_DIR` with your own paths.

If you also want to delete empty directories from the source dir, you could add this as the final line of that script:

```
find "${SOURCE_DIR}" -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm pretty new to bash and Linux in general so I will take your answer as a hint and try to implement it myself for a little longer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is already answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2503/30055

You just need to change the *.pdf to *.txt